# Zend Framework Invisible Controllers

Tags: apache, zend-framework, controller

this is a rephrasing of a question I posted yesterday. I got an answer but an incomplete one. I studied a bit and can now reformulate the question in a clear, simple way.

I create a project with Zend Framework. I get inside and I create a controller. When I try to access thr view of this new controller, it does not work. I get the "page not found" error.

I understand the problem has to do with Apache and .htaccess and that stuff. I need to know what exactly I need to know in order to get to see other pages than the main one.

G.

Comment: You need to know about how to configure apache rewrite in the .htaccess, routing with ZF and how to setup a ZF app properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ideas to try:

Have you checked the `.htaccess` file in the public_html folder?

A basic example for ZF:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Have you checked that that `AllowOverride` is enabled in the `<Directory>` configuration within your VirtualHost configuration?

```
   <Directory "/path/to/public_html">
     AllowOverride All
     Options FollowSymLinks
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow From All
   </Directory>
```